# How do I Display Two Column Flex as One Column in Responsive View?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am working on the following site.

https://sheboyganbjj.com/instructors.php

I need the instructor photos and bios to display as one column in Responsive view.

I did adding in code from other pages in the site where the two column pages display as one in Responsive view and was unsuccessful.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Links to other sites are not adequate.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that. I see why that is important. Will do.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `flex-wrap: wrap;` in your CSS for the class `.flex-container` should do the trick. This allows the content to wrap on multiple lines if it can't fit everything on one line.

Check out the following Flexbox guide, it might be of great help: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{
border:2px solid black;
display:flex;
justify-content:space-evenly;
align-items:center;
width:30%;
flex-wrap:wrap;
}
h4{
border:2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<h4>Image1</h4>
<h4>Image2</h4>
<h4>Image3</h4>
<h4>Image4</h4>
<h4>Image5</h4>
<h4>Image6</h4>

</div>
```

**caution : you have to change the width property according to your window size **
or you can use grid box layout
like

```css
 .container{
 border:2px solid black;
 display:grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
 }
 h4{
  border:2px solid black;
  width:50%;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
 <h4>Image 1</h4>
  <h4>Image 2</h4> 
  <h4>Image 3</h4>
   <h4>Image 4</h4>
    <h4>Image 5</h4>
     <h4>Image 6</h4>
 </div>
```

** you can change the width of both element according to your need**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).